# SendInput always moves mouse pointer to left top corner

Tags: c++, winapi, mouseevent

I would like to programmatically synthesize mouse motion to a point (100,100) on a screen with code below, but it moves to left top side instead. What could be wrong?

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include<Windows.h>

int main() {
  INPUT input;
  input.type = INPUT_MOUSE;
  input.mi.dx = 100;
  input.mi.dy = 100;
  input.mi.dwFlags = MOUSEEVENTF_ABSOLUTE | MOUSEEVENTF_MOVE;
  input.mi.mouseData = 0;
  input.mi.dwExtraInfo = NULL;
  input.mi.time = 0;
  SendInput(1, &input, sizeof(INPUT));
  return 0;
}
```

PS. I have compiled it in VS2017 on Windows 10x64. I have run the code on Win7 as well

PPS. When I remove MOUSEEVENTF_ABSOLUTE flag, it moves to relative position.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The API call follows [documented](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646273.aspx) behavior:

> **MOUSEEVENTF_ABSOLUTE**: The *dx* and *dy* members contain normalized absolute coordinates. [...] see the following Remarks section.

Normalized coordinates are indeed described in the *Remarks* section:

> If `MOUSEEVENTF_ABSOLUTE` value is specified, *dx* and *dy* contain normalized absolute coordinates between 0 and 65,535. The event procedure maps these coordinates onto the display surface. Coordinate (0,0) maps onto the upper-left corner of the display surface; coordinate (65535,65535) maps onto the lower-right corner. In a multimonitor system, the coordinates map to the primary monitor.

To move the mouse to an absolute position, you first need to query the display surface size (e.g. through a call to [GetMonitorInfor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd144901.aspx)), and scale the coordinates appropriately.

The following function normalizes a point, given the point and display surface dimensions in device units as input:

```
POINT normalize(POINT const& pt_in_px, RECT const& display_size_in_px)
{
    POINT pt_normalized{};

    auto const width_in_px{ display_size_in_px.right - display_size_in_px.left };
    auto const height_in_px{ display_size_in_px.bottom - display_size_in_px.top };

    pt_normalized.x = ::MulDiv(pt_in_px.x, 65536, width_in_px);
    pt_normalized.y = ::MulDiv(pt_in_px.y, 65536, height_in_px);

    return pt_normalized;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Because of small values of dx and dy in my data I have not noticed any move at all.

Comment: Haha, I just though: so this 'works' until we have 64k monitors. As if ever ;)

Comment: @JHBonarius: This does work for 64k displays just fine. Only exception is the rounding performed by `MulDiv`, that starts to map the final rows and columns to 65536, once you get closer to coordinates with values 2^32 - 1. For a hypothetical display with resolution 64k x 64k the function produces perfectly valid values.

Comment: Yes, sorry. I meant *after* 64k, so 128k etc ;). Just very hypothetical.. Imagine the bandwidth of a theoretical 128k*128k*120fps monitor... 2 TB/s xD